# How to improve the select query performance in Java?

Tags: java, performance, berkeley-db

I am using BerkeleyDB Database and I am performing `select` query that require 409 ms.  How to improve the select query performance?

I am using the following code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ReadData {

Connection con=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
Statement smt = null;

public void readData() 
{
     try
     {
         Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/D:\\DB\\Mediation.db");
         smt = con.createStatement();

         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         rs = smt.executeQuery("select * from CDRData");             
         while(rs.next())
         {
             System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" , "+rs.getString(2)+" , "+rs.getString(3)+" , "+rs.getString(4)+" , "+rs.getString(5)+" , "+rs.getString(6)+" , "+rs.getString(7)+" , "+rs.getString(8)+" , "+rs.getString(9)+" , "+rs.getString(10)+" , "+rs.getString(11)+" , "+rs.getString(12)+" , "+rs.getString(13)+" , "+rs.getString(14)+" , "+rs.getString(15)+" , "+rs.getString(16)+" , "+rs.getString(17)+" , "+rs.getString(18)+" , "+rs.getString(19)+" , "+rs.getString(20)+" , "+rs.getString(21)+" , "+rs.getString(22)+" , "+rs.getString(23));
         }
         long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println("The time taken by select query : "+(finishTime-startTime)+ " ms");
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println("Error ---- "+e);
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadData csvread = new ReadData();
    csvread.readData();
}
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get better performance out of `select * from CDRData`?

Comment: This is the time to perform the query and parse the ResultSet. You are also doing a select * which will scan the whole table. What kind of performance are you hoping for?

Comment: You might also want to skip the printing of the results.  It is possible that printing the results is creating part of the delay.

Comment: If your objective at the end of this is to create a CSV file, then I recommend http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/. Don't know how to make that query perform better though sorry

Answer (score 6):

@Dhananjay Joshi my first recomendation it's that need the change the select from `select *` and put the fields that you really need when you do a `select *` you bring a lot of fields that maybe you don't need and requires more memory

Answer (score 1):

In general terms when using JDBC you may see a performance increase by

- using a StoredProcedure - this elimentates some pre-processing by the database engine
- using a PreparedStatement - this *can* elimenate some pre-processing if you are using a query multiple times.

You can also improve time by optimising your query, perhaps by adding appropriate indexes. Using `explain` can help you understand the actions and cost that the query will ancounter.

However, in your example you are just executing a simple select with no predicate, so none of these will help you.

Comment: yeah, in our environment we seen situation by indexing the column in database table, the efficiency increase by 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything to improve with your code in terms of DB access. Selecting all rows is a trivial task for a database which basically just takes a certain amount of time. using a [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) would give you some improvement, if you repeatedly have the same/similar queries, but not in your test scenario.

You have a little overhead in your java part though which comes from allocating/concatenating string objects. You might replace your loop body by

```
 System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
 System.out.print(", ");
 System.out.print(rs.getString(2))
 // ...
```

or a StringBuilder...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time could be spent printing the results.

Try running the test without printing the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may put a printed timestamp after the "executeQuery" statement. And trying to figure out what spends more time in your program (retrive data from database or java instructions).

Theoretically, retrieving data from database would be the bottleneck if the data is large enough.